# Get Key From a Button ID That is an Array When Clicked With jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Hi I'm a bit new to jQuery. I'm trying to get the key value from a button id which is an array when clicked as shown below:

```
<button id="button[1]">Submit</button>
<button id="button[2]">Submit</button>
<button id="button[3]">Submit</button>
<button id="button[4]">Submit</button>
```

The expected result is when clicked is 1 or 2 or etc.

In PHP I would achieve this by getting the name which is an array also as shown below:

```
<html>
    <button name="button[1]">Submit</button>
    <button name="button[2]">Submit</button>
    <button name="button[3]">Submit</button>
    <button name="button[4]">Submit</button>
</html>
<?php
    key($_POST['button']);
?>
```

How would I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Add a `data-id` attribute to the buttons and read that attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` attribut is a unique label you give to an element, it is a string value and should be used only for selection. So firstly you can't just cast a string `button[1]` to an array, but this is a misuse of `id`.

You should use the `value` attribut to share this kind of information, like `<button id="button1" value="1">text here</button>` and read it with `$('#button1').value()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "button[name^='button']" ).on('click',function(){
var str = ($(this).attr('name'));
 var matches = str.match(/(\d+)/);
            
     alert(matches[0]); 
        
});
```

this will make a click listener on all the button with name value satrting with buttton. so when u click on it it will alert the current click button name key attribute value

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a better way to manage this case , you can use button `id` attribute you can assign each button a unique number :

```
<html>
    <button id="1">Submit</button>
    <button id="2">Submit</button>
    <button id="3">Submit</button>
    <button id="4">Submit</button>
</html>
```

and create a jquery function to catch the click event on button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      $(this).attr('id'); // here you get the id value of selected button
    }
}
```